# $request->request is null in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to define a Middleware FederationMiddleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd($request->request); // prints null
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $userLogged = Auth::user();
        if (!$userLogged->isSuperAdmin()) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException;
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

In Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = array( 
     ...
    'federation' => Middleware\FederationMiddleware::class,
```

In my controller, I have:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('federation'); 
}
```

What I need basically, is to allow federation's owner to edit his own information, so, I need to parse the URL to know that if URL contains federations/{federationID} and federationID == user->federation()->id, grant access

Comment: try just debugging with dd($request->getMethod()) instead of dd($request->request) as if it's not a POST request it will be null

Comment: it is a GET, but $request shouldn't give me URL Params?

Comment: ->query will give you GET parameters i'm pretty sure. As it uses Symfony Request class

Comment: query returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need something more advanced, you could just parse it from the current url and make a check.

```
$path = $request->path();
if (preg_match('@^federation/(\d+)/edit$@', $path, $match)) {
    $federationId = $match[1];
    // compare with the user's federation id here
}
```

This will match `sitename.xyz/federation/[somedigits]/edit` and no other addresses.

Comment: I'm baaaaad with regex. but in this case, I would need to compare exactly if url is /federations/{id}/edit/ because there is a lot of more url than could contains federationId

Comment: I understand. Please see my edited answer, I think that's why you want?

Comment: it doesn't answer my question, but it appears to solve my problem ! tx